# iOS Swift how recreate barcode Image after scan

Tags: ios, swift, barcode, avcapturesession, core-image

We were asked an iOS app which detects **barcodes(code128, code93, code39 are the possible types)**, and after detecting we need to recreate the image and show the barcode in the main view.
To detect the barcode we are using `AVCaptureSession` framework, to generate the image we use `CoreImage`.

I am able to detect the barcodes string values, but I get nil when I try to get `CIBarcodeDescriptor` field, so I am not able to pass this info in the CoreImage section.

**Here's my code**

Detecting barcode delegate

```
public func scannerDelegate(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject],from connection: AVCaptureConnection){

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first{

        guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else{
            return
        }
        //barcode String id
        guard let barcodeStringValue = readableObject.stringValue else{
            return
        }

        //readableObject.descriptor
        guard let descriptor = readableObject.descriptor else{
            return
        }
         //Pass parameters to the caller and stop Capture Session
    }
}
```

**To generate the Barcode Image**

```
    let filterName = descriptor.rawValue
    guard let data = barcodeStringValue.data(using: .ascii),
      let filter = CIFilter(name: filterName) else {
            return nil
    }

    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    guard let image = filter.outputImage else {
        return nil
    }
```

So I am not able to pass filterName parameter in the `CIFilter` class, I tested this solution for QRCode and it works perfectly, Can I achieve the same result with barcodes? Or should I use an external library to do the job?

Comment: what is your filter name, can you please post the new of filter you are using?

Comment: This is my problem, I am not able to declare filterName cause I have nil descriptor, and I am not able to get other info about barcode type from AVMetadataObject

Comment: Use `CIQRCodeGenerator` as filter name

Comment: @Lu_ it creates a QRCode, it doesn't work

Comment: how it does not work? what result do you want to achieve then? if you want different type of code displayed pass that type of filter

Comment: I need to detect the filter from barcode scan, this I am not able to achieve